# Cambiar posición de botones

Tags: javascript, html, css

quería preguntar si sabía la manera de hacer que unos botones cambien de posición aleatoria-mente cada vez que se refresque el navegador o usando el botón "Aleatorio"

Gracias

Adjunto código HTML y CSS

```css
.style {
  background: orange;
  color: black;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:15pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.random{
  background: green;
  color:white;
  font-family: 'Tahoma';
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<input value ="Aleatorio" type="button" id="random" class="random"></td>
<table>
<td>  <input value=" 1 " data-number="1" onclick="number(1)" type="button" id="1" class="style"></td>    
<td>  <input value=" 2 " data-number="2" onclick="number(2)" type="button" id="2" class="style"</td>
<td>  <input value=" 3 " data-number="3" onclick="number(3)" type="button" id="3" class="style"></td>
</tr>


<td>  <input value=" 4 " data-number="4" onclick="number(4)" type="button" id="cuatro" class="style"></td>
<td>  <input value=" 5 " data-number="5" onclick="number(5)" type="button" id="cinco" class="style"></td>
<td>  <input value=" 6 " data-number="6" onclick="number(6)" type="button" id="seis" class="style"></td>
```

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Con Javascript es bien sencillo, sólo tienes que "barajar" los número del 1 al 6 y luego insertarlos en los 6 botones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el ejemplo te faltaban cerrar ciertas etiquetas y agregar otras tantas, también se reemplazo el nombre de los **ID**.

Este código que te comparto hace lo que necesitas:

```js
//Aqui asignas la funcionalidad Click al botón, una vez se ha cargado el documento

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#random").click(function () {
        var numeros =  [1,2,3,4,5,6];
        numeros.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });
        $.each(numeros, function(index, value) {
          $('#n' + index).val(value);
        });
  });

});
```

```css
.style {
  background: orange;
  color: black;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:15pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.random{
  background: green;
  color:white;
  font-family: 'Tahoma';
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  value ="Aleatorio" type="button" id="random" class="random"></td> 
<table>
     <tr>
      <td><input value="1" data-number="1" onclick="number(1)" type="button" id="n0" class="style"></td>
      <td><input value="2" data-number="2" onclick="number(2)" type="button" id="n1" class="style"></td>
      <td><input value="3" data-number="3" onclick="number(3)" type="button" id="n2" class="style"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>  <input value="4" data-number="4" onclick="number(4)" type="button" id="n3" class="style"></td>
      <td>  <input value="5" data-number="5" onclick="number(5)" type="button" id="n4" class="style"></td>
      <td>  <input value="6" data-number="6" onclick="number(6)" type="button" id="n5" class="style"></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira, te muestro en este ejemplo lo que pasa.

```js
$('.estilo').hover(function(){
    $('.estilo').each(function(){
      $(this).val(" * ");
    });
});

$('.estilo').mouseout(function(){
  $('.estilo').each(function(){
     let val = $(this).data('number');
      $(this).val( val );
  });
});

    document.title = "ejemplo teclado";

    <!----- variable para imprimir numeros
    var answer_mode = 0;    

    <!----- función para limpiar la pantalla
    function clear1() {
        document.forms["teclado"].display.value = "";
    }
    
    function clear() {
        clear1();
    }

    function number(ch) {
        if (answer_mode) {
        clear1();
        answer_mode = 0;
        }    
        document.forms["teclado"].display.value += ch;
        var hoja=ch
    }

  function randomNumbers(){

     var values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
     var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
     
     //Barajea los valores
     for(var i=-1; i<random; i++){
       var item = values.shift();
       values.push(item);
     } 
     
     for(var i=1; i<=values.length; i++){
     
       var currentNumber =  values[i-1];
       var inputObject = document.getElementById('input_'+i);
       inputObject.value = currentNumber;
       inputObject.setAttribute("data-number",currentNumber);
     } 
  }
  //random numbers in each refresh
  randomNumbers();
```

```css
.estilo {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  font-size:30px;
  color:blue
}

.c {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  font-size:30px;
  color:blue
}

button {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="teclado">

<input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="display" value="" size="8" style="text: Arial; font-size: 20pt; background-color:#58D3F7" >
<table>

<tbody>

<tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  
<td>  <input value=" 7 " data-number="7" onclick="number(7)" type="button" id="input_7" class="estilo"></td>    
<td>  <input value=" 8 " data-number="8" onclick="number(8)" type="button" id="input_8" class="estilo"</td>
<td>  <input value=" 9 " data-number="9" onclick="number(9)" type="button" id="input_9" class="estilo"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>  <input value=" 4 " data-number="4" onclick="number(4)" type="button" id="input_4" class="estilo"></td>
<td>  <input value=" 5 " data-number="5" onclick="number(5)" type="button" id="input_5" class="estilo"></td>
<td>  <input value=" 6 " data-number="6" onclick="number(6)" type="button" id="input_6" class="estilo"></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>  <input value=" 1 " data-number="1" onclick="number(1)" type="button" id="input_1" class="estilo"></td>
<td>  <input value=" 2 " data-number="2" onclick="number(2)" type="button" id="input_2" class="estilo"></td>
<td>  <input value=" 3 " data-number="3" onclick="number(3)" type="button" id="input_3" class="estilo"></td>
</tr>



<td><input value=" 0 " data-number="0" onclick="number(0)" type="button" id="input_10" class="estilo"></td>

<td></td>

<td>  <input value="C" onclick="clear1()" type="button" class="c"></td>

<td></td>
<button class="btn" type="ver">Mostrar URL</button>
```

Al enviarlo solo visualmente me cambia los textos, pero permanecen igual. Quisiera hacerlo tanto con este tipo de ejemplo porque son varias temáticas y una de ellas es con imágenes también.

Disculpa tanta pregunta.

Answer (score -1):

Hola te dejo un ejemplo de como barajear los valores utilizando la función shift.

```js
  function randomNumbers(){

     var values = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
     var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
     
     //Barajea los valores
     for(var i=0; i<random; i++){
       var item = values.shift();
       values.push(item);
     } 
     
     for(var i=1; i<=values.length; i++){
     
       var currentNumber =  values[i-1];
       var inputObject = document.getElementById('input_'+i);
       inputObject.value = currentNumber;
       inputObject.setAttribute("data-number",currentNumber);
     } 
  }
  //random numbers in each refresh
  randomNumbers();
```

```css
.style {
  background: orange;
  color: black;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.random {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Tahoma';
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <input onclick="randomNumbers()" value="Aleatorio" type="button" id="random" class="random"></td>
  <table>
    <td> <input value=" 1 " data-number="1" onclick="number(1)" type="button" id="input_1" class="style"></td>
    <td> <input value=" 2 " data-number="2" onclick="number(2)" type="button" id="input_2" class="style" </td>
      <td> <input value=" 3 " data-number="3" onclick="number(3)" type="button" id="input_3" class="style"></td>
      </tr>
      <td> <input value=" 4 " data-number="4" onclick="number(4)" type="button" id="input_4" class="style"></td>
      <td> <input value=" 5 " data-number="5" onclick="number(5)" type="button" id="input_5" class="style"></td>
      <td> <input value=" 6 " data-number="6" onclick="number(6)" type="button" id="input_6" class="style"></td>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ambas respuesta tienen de a 1 parte de lo que necesito, uno aporta la solución con botón y otro con refresh... ¿Qué procede?

Comment: Bueno si me acabo de encontrar con algo, a la hora de verlo, sí cambian visualmente, pero el valor "data-number" no se cambia, permanecen en la misma posición. ¿Qué podría hacer para que igual esta propiedad se mueva con todo?

Comment: @Eriold El codigo si cambia el valor del atributo data-number, si miras el codigo solo fue necesario meter el codigo js dentro de una funcion y asociarlo con el boton de aleatorio.